# logic behind printing square spiral pattern (no array)

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, math

i want to make the square spiral pattern.
i already make it with array before.
i just don't get it the pattern.
how to print the inside of the spiral ?

Input = 5

```
#####
....#
###.#
#...#
#####
```

Input = 11

```
###########
..........#
#########.#
#.......#.#
#.#####.#.#
#.#...#.#.#
#.#.###.#.#
#.#.....#.#
#.#######.#
#.........#
###########
```

Comment: You must provide some code so other users have something to help you with.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i've tried this for the outer spiral
[link] (https://ideone.com/fork/RarhZZ)

Comment: Look for the pattern and figure out how to put it into a loop. Count the number of #'s and spaces in each line, and try to figure out how that line is related to the lines above or below it. Hint: split it up into multiple patterns, a line can be related to another line that's not directly above or below it, the first line doesn't follow the pattern exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at the problem From different angle. If you look at this pattern from the side you get: (for input 11)

```
#########.# (1)
#.......#.# (2)
#.#####.#.# (3)
#.#...#.#.# (4)
#.#.#.#.#.# (5)
#.#.#.#.#.# (6)
#.#.###.#.# (7)
#.#.....#.# (8)
#.#######.# (9)
#.........# (10)
########### (11)
```

Now, the lower part of this pattern is easy to draw (lines 6-11).
Notice that if you draw the same row again, but this time upside-down you get very similar for your desire output - when the diff matrix for the upper 5 line are

```
00000000010 (diff for line 1 and 11)
00000000100 (diff for line 2 and 10)
00000001000 (diff for line 3 and 9)
00000010000 (diff for line 4 and 8)
00000100000 (diff for line 5 and 7)
```

So all you left to do looping on the upper part of the array and swap the sign on those places - again, this matrix has easy pattern.

Comment: I recommend that you do not answer such low-quality questions, where the questioner shows no work of his own.